Error with ceph-osd (exit code -11) when adding a new OSD
I'm adding a new node to my ceph cluster but I'm having issues creating the osd service in it.
All services are starting properly, but the osd service is falling.
When I run the command:
sudo ceph orch daemon add osd pi-MkII:/dev/sda

I get the following error:
Error EINVAL: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/share/ceph/mgr/mgr_module.py", line 1809, in _handle_command
    return self.handle_command(inbuf, cmd)
  File "/usr/share/ceph/mgr/orchestrator/_interface.py", line 183, in handle_command
    return dispatch[cmd['prefix']].call(self, cmd, inbuf)
  File "/usr/share/ceph/mgr/mgr_module.py", line 474, in call
    return self.func(mgr, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/share/ceph/mgr/orchestrator/_interface.py", line 119, in <lambda>
    wrapper_copy = lambda *l_args, **l_kwargs: wrapper(*l_args, **l_kwargs)  # noqa: E731
  File "/usr/share/ceph/mgr/orchestrator/_interface.py", line 108, in wrapper
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/share/ceph/mgr/orchestrator/module.py", line 1279, in _daemon_add_osd
    raise_if_exception(completion)
  File "/usr/share/ceph/mgr/orchestrator/_interface.py", line 240, in raise_if_exception
    raise e
RuntimeError: cephadm exited with an error code: 1, stderr:Inferring config /var/lib/ceph/90f6049c-dce8-11ed-aead-ef938bdeca07/mon.pi-MkII/config
Non-zero exit code 1 from /usr/bin/docker run --rm --ipc=host --stop-signal=SIGTERM --ulimit nofile=1048576 --net=host --entrypoint /usr/sbin/ceph-volume --privileged --group-add=disk --init -e CONTAINER_IMAGE=quay.io/ceph/ceph@sha256:6ac7f923aa1d23b43248ce0ddec7e1388855ee3d00813b52c3172b0b23b37906 -e NODE_NAME=pi-MkII -e CEPH_USE_RANDOM_NONCE=1 -e CEPH_VOLUME_OSDSPEC_AFFINITY=None -e CEPH_VOLUME_SKIP_RESTORECON=yes -e CEPH_VOLUME_DEBUG=1 -v /var/run/ceph/90f6049c-dce8-11ed-aead-ef938bdeca07:/var/run/ceph:z -v /var/log/ceph/90f6049c-dce8-11ed-aead-ef938bdeca07:/var/log/ceph:z -v /var/lib/ceph/90f6049c-dce8-11ed-aead-ef938bdeca07/crash:/var/lib/ceph/crash:z -v /dev:/dev -v /run/udev:/run/udev -v /sys:/sys -v /run/lvm:/run/lvm -v /run/lock/lvm:/run/lock/lvm -v /:/rootfs -v /tmp/ceph-tmpxkkx8pn4:/etc/ceph/ceph.conf:z -v /tmp/ceph-tmp_002tzt9:/var/lib/ceph/bootstrap-osd/ceph.keyring:z quay.io/ceph/ceph@sha256:6ac7f923aa1d23b43248ce0ddec7e1388855ee3d00813b52c3172b0b23b37906 lvm batch --no-auto /dev/sda --yes --no-systemd
/usr/bin/docker: stderr --> passed data devices: 1 physical, 0 LVM
/usr/bin/docker: stderr --> relative data size: 1.0
/usr/bin/docker: stderr Running command: /usr/bin/ceph-authtool --gen-print-key
/usr/bin/docker: stderr Running command: /usr/bin/ceph --cluster ceph --name client.bootstrap-osd --keyring /var/lib/ceph/bootstrap-osd/ceph.keyring -i - osd new edd6a99a-8aef-4f2a-babe-2817b7b55131
/usr/bin/docker: stderr Running command: nsenter --mount=/rootfs/proc/1/ns/mnt --ipc=/rootfs/proc/1/ns/ipc --net=/rootfs/proc/1/ns/net --uts=/rootfs/proc/1/ns/uts /sbin/vgcreate --force --yes ceph-e9a5d302-667b-425e-b96f-49cd9b76bbae /dev/sda
/usr/bin/docker: stderr  stdout: Physical volume "/dev/sda" successfully created.
/usr/bin/docker: stderr  stdout: Volume group "ceph-e9a5d302-667b-425e-b96f-49cd9b76bbae" successfully created
/usr/bin/docker: stderr Running command: nsenter --mount=/rootfs/proc/1/ns/mnt --ipc=/rootfs/proc/1/ns/ipc --net=/rootfs/proc/1/ns/net --uts=/rootfs/proc/1/ns/uts /sbin/lvcreate --yes -l 119227 -n osd-block-edd6a99a-8aef-4f2a-babe-2817b7b55131 ceph-e9a5d302-667b-425e-b96f-49cd9b76bbae
/usr/bin/docker: stderr  stdout: Logical volume "osd-block-edd6a99a-8aef-4f2a-babe-2817b7b55131" created.
/usr/bin/docker: stderr Running command: /usr/bin/ceph-authtool --gen-print-key
/usr/bin/docker: stderr Running command: /usr/bin/mount -t tmpfs tmpfs /var/lib/ceph/osd/ceph-1
/usr/bin/docker: stderr Running command: /usr/bin/chown -h ceph:ceph /dev/ceph-e9a5d302-667b-425e-b96f-49cd9b76bbae/osd-block-edd6a99a-8aef-4f2a-babe-2817b7b55131
/usr/bin/docker: stderr Running command: /usr/bin/chown -R ceph:ceph /dev/dm-0
/usr/bin/docker: stderr Running command: /usr/bin/ln -s /dev/ceph-e9a5d302-667b-425e-b96f-49cd9b76bbae/osd-block-edd6a99a-8aef-4f2a-babe-2817b7b55131 /var/lib/ceph/osd/ceph-1/block
/usr/bin/docker: stderr Running command: /usr/bin/ceph --cluster ceph --name client.bootstrap-osd --keyring /var/lib/ceph/bootstrap-osd/ceph.keyring mon getmap -o /var/lib/ceph/osd/ceph-1/activate.monmap
/usr/bin/docker: stderr  stderr: got monmap epoch 19
/usr/bin/docker: stderr --> Creating keyring file for osd.1
/usr/bin/docker: stderr Running command: /usr/bin/chown -R ceph:ceph /var/lib/ceph/osd/ceph-1/keyring
/usr/bin/docker: stderr Running command: /usr/bin/chown -R ceph:ceph /var/lib/ceph/osd/ceph-1/
/usr/bin/docker: stderr Running command: /usr/bin/ceph-osd --cluster ceph --osd-objectstore bluestore --mkfs -i 1 --monmap /var/lib/ceph/osd/ceph-1/activate.monmap --keyfile - --osdspec-affinity None --osd-data /var/lib/ceph/osd/ceph-1/ --osd-uuid edd6a99a-8aef-4f2a-babe-2817b7b55131 --setuser ceph --setgroup ceph
/usr/bin/docker: stderr --> Was unable to complete a new OSD, will rollback changes
/usr/bin/docker: stderr Running command: /usr/bin/ceph --cluster ceph --name client.bootstrap-osd --keyring /var/lib/ceph/bootstrap-osd/ceph.keyring osd purge-new osd.1 --yes-i-really-mean-it
/usr/bin/docker: stderr  stderr: purged osd.1
/usr/bin/docker: stderr --> Zapping: /dev/ceph-e9a5d302-667b-425e-b96f-49cd9b76bbae/osd-block-edd6a99a-8aef-4f2a-babe-2817b7b55131
/usr/bin/docker: stderr --> Unmounting /var/lib/ceph/osd/ceph-1
/usr/bin/docker: stderr Running command: /usr/bin/umount -v /var/lib/ceph/osd/ceph-1
/usr/bin/docker: stderr  stderr: umount: /var/lib/ceph/osd/ceph-1 unmounted
/usr/bin/docker: stderr Running command: /usr/bin/dd if=/dev/zero of=/dev/ceph-e9a5d302-667b-425e-b96f-49cd9b76bbae/osd-block-edd6a99a-8aef-4f2a-babe-2817b7b55131 bs=1M count=10 conv=fsync
/usr/bin/docker: stderr  stderr: 10+0 records in
/usr/bin/docker: stderr 10+0 records out
/usr/bin/docker: stderr  stderr: 10485760 bytes (10 MB, 10 MiB) copied, 0.0823937 s, 127 MB/s
/usr/bin/docker: stderr --> Only 1 LV left in VG, will proceed to destroy volume group ceph-e9a5d302-667b-425e-b96f-49cd9b76bbae
/usr/bin/docker: stderr Running command: nsenter --mount=/rootfs/proc/1/ns/mnt --ipc=/rootfs/proc/1/ns/ipc --net=/rootfs/proc/1/ns/net --uts=/rootfs/proc/1/ns/uts /sbin/vgremove -v -f ceph-e9a5d302-667b-425e-b96f-49cd9b76bbae
/usr/bin/docker: stderr  stderr: Removing ceph--e9a5d302--667b--425e--b96f--49cd9b76bbae-osd--block--edd6a99a--8aef--4f2a--babe--2817b7b55131 (253:0)
/usr/bin/docker: stderr  stderr: Archiving volume group "ceph-e9a5d302-667b-425e-b96f-49cd9b76bbae" metadata (seqno 5).
/usr/bin/docker: stderr  stderr: Releasing logical volume "osd-block-edd6a99a-8aef-4f2a-babe-2817b7b55131"
/usr/bin/docker: stderr  stderr: Creating volume group backup "/etc/lvm/backup/ceph-e9a5d302-667b-425e-b96f-49cd9b76bbae" (seqno 6).
/usr/bin/docker: stderr  stdout: Logical volume "osd-block-edd6a99a-8aef-4f2a-babe-2817b7b55131" successfully removed
/usr/bin/docker: stderr  stderr: Removing physical volume "/dev/sda" from volume group "ceph-e9a5d302-667b-425e-b96f-49cd9b76bbae"
/usr/bin/docker: stderr  stdout: Volume group "ceph-e9a5d302-667b-425e-b96f-49cd9b76bbae" successfully removed
/usr/bin/docker: stderr Running command: nsenter --mount=/rootfs/proc/1/ns/mnt --ipc=/rootfs/proc/1/ns/ipc --net=/rootfs/proc/1/ns/net --uts=/rootfs/proc/1/ns/uts /sbin/pvremove -v -f -f /dev/sda
/usr/bin/docker: stderr  stdout: Labels on physical volume "/dev/sda" successfully wiped.
/usr/bin/docker: stderr --> Zapping successful for OSD: 1
/usr/bin/docker: stderr Traceback (most recent call last):
/usr/bin/docker: stderr   File "/usr/sbin/ceph-volume", line 33, in <module>
/usr/bin/docker: stderr     sys.exit(load_entry_point('ceph-volume==1.0.0', 'console_scripts', 'ceph-volume')())
/usr/bin/docker: stderr   File "/usr/lib/python3.9/site-packages/ceph_volume/main.py", line 41, in __init__
/usr/bin/docker: stderr     self.main(self.argv)
/usr/bin/docker: stderr   File "/usr/lib/python3.9/site-packages/ceph_volume/decorators.py", line 59, in newfunc
/usr/bin/docker: stderr     return f(*a, **kw)
/usr/bin/docker: stderr   File "/usr/lib/python3.9/site-packages/ceph_volume/main.py", line 153, in main
/usr/bin/docker: stderr     terminal.dispatch(self.mapper, subcommand_args)
/usr/bin/docker: stderr   File "/usr/lib/python3.9/site-packages/ceph_volume/terminal.py", line 194, in dispatch
/usr/bin/docker: stderr     instance.main()
/usr/bin/docker: stderr   File "/usr/lib/python3.9/site-packages/ceph_volume/devices/lvm/main.py", line 46, in main
/usr/bin/docker: stderr     terminal.dispatch(self.mapper, self.argv)
/usr/bin/docker: stderr   File "/usr/lib/python3.9/site-packages/ceph_volume/terminal.py", line 194, in dispatch
/usr/bin/docker: stderr     instance.main()
/usr/bin/docker: stderr   File "/usr/lib/python3.9/site-packages/ceph_volume/decorators.py", line 16, in is_root
/usr/bin/docker: stderr     return func(*a, **kw)
/usr/bin/docker: stderr   File "/usr/lib/python3.9/site-packages/ceph_volume/devices/lvm/batch.py", line 414, in main
/usr/bin/docker: stderr     self._execute(plan)
/usr/bin/docker: stderr   File "/usr/lib/python3.9/site-packages/ceph_volume/devices/lvm/batch.py", line 432, in _execute
/usr/bin/docker: stderr     c.create(argparse.Namespace(**args))
/usr/bin/docker: stderr   File "/usr/lib/python3.9/site-packages/ceph_volume/decorators.py", line 16, in is_root
/usr/bin/docker: stderr     return func(*a, **kw)
/usr/bin/docker: stderr   File "/usr/lib/python3.9/site-packages/ceph_volume/devices/lvm/create.py", line 26, in create
/usr/bin/docker: stderr     prepare_step.safe_prepare(args)
/usr/bin/docker: stderr   File "/usr/lib/python3.9/site-packages/ceph_volume/devices/lvm/prepare.py", line 196, in safe_prepare
/usr/bin/docker: stderr     self.prepare()
/usr/bin/docker: stderr   File "/usr/lib/python3.9/site-packages/ceph_volume/decorators.py", line 16, in is_root
/usr/bin/docker: stderr     return func(*a, **kw)
/usr/bin/docker: stderr   File "/usr/lib/python3.9/site-packages/ceph_volume/devices/lvm/prepare.py", line 278, in prepare
/usr/bin/docker: stderr     prepare_bluestore(
/usr/bin/docker: stderr   File "/usr/lib/python3.9/site-packages/ceph_volume/devices/lvm/prepare.py", line 59, in prepare_bluestore
/usr/bin/docker: stderr     prepare_utils.osd_mkfs_bluestore(
/usr/bin/docker: stderr   File "/usr/lib/python3.9/site-packages/ceph_volume/util/prepare.py", line 459, in osd_mkfs_bluestore
/usr/bin/docker: stderr     raise RuntimeError('Command failed with exit code %s: %s' % (returncode, ' '.join(command)))
/usr/bin/docker: stderr RuntimeError: Command failed with exit code -11: /usr/bin/ceph-osd --cluster ceph --osd-objectstore bluestore --mkfs -i 1 --monmap /var/lib/ceph/osd/ceph-1/activate.monmap --keyfile - --osdspec-affinity None --osd-data /var/lib/ceph/osd/ceph-1/ --osd-uuid edd6a99a-8aef-4f2a-babe-2817b7b55131 --setuser ceph --setgroup ceph
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.10/runpy.py", line 196, in _run_module_as_main
    return _run_code(code, main_globals, None,
  File "/usr/lib/python3.10/runpy.py", line 86, in _run_code
    exec(code, run_globals)
  File "/var/lib/ceph/90f6049c-dce8-11ed-aead-ef938bdeca07/cephadm.91b52e446d8f1d91339889933063a5070027dc00f54d563f523727c6dd22b172/__main__.py", line 10889, in <module>
  File "/var/lib/ceph/90f6049c-dce8-11ed-aead-ef938bdeca07/cephadm.91b52e446d8f1d91339889933063a5070027dc00f54d563f523727c6dd22b172/__main__.py", line 10877, in main
  File "/var/lib/ceph/90f6049c-dce8-11ed-aead-ef938bdeca07/cephadm.91b52e446d8f1d91339889933063a5070027dc00f54d563f523727c6dd22b172/__main__.py", line 2576, in _infer_config
  File "/var/lib/ceph/90f6049c-dce8-11ed-aead-ef938bdeca07/cephadm.91b52e446d8f1d91339889933063a5070027dc00f54d563f523727c6dd22b172/__main__.py", line 2492, in _infer_fsid
  File "/var/lib/ceph/90f6049c-dce8-11ed-aead-ef938bdeca07/cephadm.91b52e446d8f1d91339889933063a5070027dc00f54d563f523727c6dd22b172/__main__.py", line 2604, in _infer_image
  File "/var/lib/ceph/90f6049c-dce8-11ed-aead-ef938bdeca07/cephadm.91b52e446d8f1d91339889933063a5070027dc00f54d563f523727c6dd22b172/__main__.py", line 2479, in _validate_fsid
  File "/var/lib/ceph/90f6049c-dce8-11ed-aead-ef938bdeca07/cephadm.91b52e446d8f1d91339889933063a5070027dc00f54d563f523727c6dd22b172/__main__.py", line 7145, in command_ceph_volume
  File "/var/lib/ceph/90f6049c-dce8-11ed-aead-ef938bdeca07/cephadm.91b52e446d8f1d91339889933063a5070027dc00f54d563f523727c6dd22b172/__main__.py", line 2267, in call_throws
RuntimeError: Failed command: /usr/bin/docker run --rm --ipc=host --stop-signal=SIGTERM --ulimit nofile=1048576 --net=host --entrypoint /usr/sbin/ceph-volume --privileged --group-add=disk --init -e CONTAINER_IMAGE=quay.io/ceph/ceph@sha256:6ac7f923aa1d23b43248ce0ddec7e1388855ee3d00813b52c3172b0b23b37906 -e NODE_NAME=pi-MkII -e CEPH_USE_RANDOM_NONCE=1 -e CEPH_VOLUME_OSDSPEC_AFFINITY=None -e CEPH_VOLUME_SKIP_RESTORECON=yes -e CEPH_VOLUME_DEBUG=1 -v /var/run/ceph/90f6049c-dce8-11ed-aead-ef938bdeca07:/var/run/ceph:z -v /var/log/ceph/90f6049c-dce8-11ed-aead-ef938bdeca07:/var/log/ceph:z -v /var/lib/ceph/90f6049c-dce8-11ed-aead-ef938bdeca07/crash:/var/lib/ceph/crash:z -v /dev:/dev -v /run/udev:/run/udev -v /sys:/sys -v /run/lvm:/run/lvm -v /run/lock/lvm:/run/lock/lvm -v /:/rootfs -v /tmp/ceph-tmpxkkx8pn4:/etc/ceph/ceph.conf:z -v /tmp/ceph-tmp_002tzt9:/var/lib/ceph/bootstrap-osd/ceph.keyring:z quay.io/ceph/ceph@sha256:6ac7f923aa1d23b43248ce0ddec7e1388855ee3d00813b52c3172b0b23b37906 lvm batch --no-auto /dev/sda --yes --no-systemd

The device seems to be OK, as shown by the smartctl command:
sudo smartctl -a /dev/sda
smartctl 7.2 2020-12-30 r5155 [aarch64-linux-5.15.0-1061-raspi] (local build)
Copyright (C) 2002-20, Bruce Allen, Christian Franke, www.smartmontools.org

=== START OF INFORMATION SECTION ===
Model Number:                       WDS500G2X0C-00L350
Serial Number:                      1837C9800649
Firmware Version:                   101140WD
PCI Vendor/Subsystem ID:            0x15b7
IEEE OUI Identifier:                0x001b44
Total NVM Capacity:                 500,107,862,016 [500 GB]
Unallocated NVM Capacity:           0
Controller ID:                      8215
NVMe Version:                       1.3
Number of Namespaces:               1
Namespace 1 Size/Capacity:          500,107,862,016 [500 GB]
Namespace 1 Formatted LBA Size:     512
Namespace 1 IEEE EUI-64:            001b44 8b4468a31d
Local Time is:                      Tue Aug 27 11:04:36 2024 CEST
Firmware Updates (0x14):            2 Slots, no Reset required
Optional Admin Commands (0x0017):   Security Format Frmw_DL Self_Test
Optional NVM Commands (0x001f):     Comp Wr_Unc DS_Mngmt Wr_Zero Sav/Sel_Feat
Log Page Attributes (0x02):         Cmd_Eff_Lg
Maximum Data Transfer Size:         128 Pages
Warning  Comp. Temp. Threshold:     80 Celsius
Critical Comp. Temp. Threshold:     85 Celsius
Namespace 1 Features (0x02):        NA_Fields

Supported Power States
St Op     Max   Active     Idle   RL RT WL WT  Ent_Lat  Ex_Lat
 0 +     5.50W       -        -    0  0  0  0        0       0
 1 +     3.50W       -        -    1  1  1  1        0       0
 2 +     3.00W       -        -    2  2  2  2        0       0
 3 -   0.0700W       -        -    3  3  3  3     4000   10000
 4 -   0.0025W       -        -    4  4  4  4     4000   45000

Supported LBA Sizes (NSID 0x1)
Id Fmt  Data  Metadt  Rel_Perf
 0 +     512       0         2
 1 -    4096       0         1

=== START OF SMART DATA SECTION ===
SMART overall-health self-assessment test result: PASSED

SMART/Health Information (NVMe Log 0x02)
Critical Warning:                   0x00
Temperature:                        56 Celsius
Available Spare:                    100%
Available Spare Threshold:          10%
Percentage Used:                    0%
Data Units Read:                    395,073,562 [202 TB]
Data Units Written:                 201,415,687 [103 TB]
Host Read Commands:                 4,885,545,206
Host Write Commands:                4,442,317,441
Controller Busy Time:               22,634
Power Cycles:                       1,907
Power On Hours:                     47,873
Unsafe Shutdowns:                   115
Media and Data Integrity Errors:    0
Error Information Log Entries:      0
Warning  Comp. Temperature Time:    0
Critical Comp. Temperature Time:    0

Warning: NVMe Get Log truncated to 0x200 bytes, 0x200 bytes zero filled
Error Information (NVMe Log 0x01, 16 of 256 entries)
No Errors Logged

I'm not sure what's the issue.
ceph 18.2.2 is running inside docker (Docker version 27.1.2, build d01f264) and the host machine is a Raspberry Pi with Ubuntu 22.04 freshly installed.
